# Filter array of objects based on filter input

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to be able to filter my flatlist full of activitys to do in the area of the user such as going to a cinema.

[image: funtionality of the app]

and here is the filter itself:

[image: filter functionality]

## the user can select:

**Location (locatie label)**: indoor OR outdoor OR nothing.

**Intensity (Inspanning label)**: Intense (inspanning) OR Not intense (ontspanning) OR nothing.

**Composition (Samenstelling)**: Alone (Alleen) AND/OR Friends (Vrienden) AND/OR Coupple (Partner) AND/OR Family with kids (Gezin met kinderen) AND/OR Group (groep) AND/OR Colleagues (Collega's)

**So each filter section can be left out and for example composition can be used and location and the others not**

And when Show (Toon) is pressed the filtered results are showed into the flatlist.

I have tried creating the code for this problem and testing it out in my database is not working at all, i get different results.

I have tried to filter the array including the objects, that works but I just get the wrong results.

**example database data:**

```
[{
  Naam: 'Vue cinema',
  Location_Indoor: 0,
  Location_Outdoor: 1,
  Soort_Inspanning: 1,
  Soort_Ontspanning: 0,
  Samenstelling_Alleen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Vrienden: 0,
  Samenstelling_Stellen: 0,
  Samenstelling_Gezin_Kinderen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Groepen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Bedrijven: 1
}, {
  Naam: 'Shooting range',
  Location_Indoor: 0,
  Location_Outdoor: 1,
  Soort_Inspanning: 1,
  Soort_Ontspanning: 0,
  Samenstelling_Alleen: 0,
  Samenstelling_Vrienden: 1,
  Samenstelling_Stellen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Gezin_Kinderen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Groepen: 1,
  Samenstelling_Bedrijven: 0
}]
```

```js
_filterFunction = (
  locationInput, // 0 == Indoor location, 1 == Outdoor location
  intensityInput, // 0 == Intensity Intense, 1 == Intensity Not Intense
  aloneSelected, // Alone option selected? BOOL
  friendsSelected, // Friends option selected? BOOL
  partnersSelected, // Coupple option selected? BOOL
  familyWithKidsSelected, // Family with kids selected? BOOL
  groupSelected, // Group selected? BOOL
  colleaugesSelected // Colleagues select? BOOL) => {
  let locationOutdoor = false;
  let intensityIntense = false;

  //6this.state.oldData == datasource
  const newData = this.state.oldData.filter(item => {
    const outdoorData = `${item.Locatie_Outdoor}`;
    const intensityData = `${item.Soort_Ontspanning}`;
    const compositionAloneData = `${item.Samenstelling_Alleen}`;
    const compositionFriendsData = `${item.Samenstelling_Vrienden}`;
    const compositionPartnersData = `${item.Samenstelling_Stellen}`;
    const compositionFamilyWithKidsData = `${item.Samenstelling_Gezin_Kinderen}`;
    const compositionGroupsData = `${item.Samenstelling_Groepen}`;
    const compositionColleagues = `${item.Samenstelling_Bedrijven}`;

    if (outdoorData == locationInput) {
      locationOutdoor = 1;
    } else if (intensityData == intensityInput) {
      intensityIntense = 1;
    }

    if (locationOutdoor && !intensityIntense) {
      console.log('alleen location');
      return locationInput == outdoorData;
    } else if (locationOutdoor &&
      intensityIntense &&
      !aloneSelected &&
      !friendsSelected &&
      !partnersSelected &&
      !familyWithKidsSelected &&
      !groupSelected &&
      !colleaugesSelected) { //if only location outdoor and intensityIntense == selected and not composition
      console.log('location en intensity');
      return (
        locationInput == outdoorData &&
        intensityInput == intensityData
      );
    } else if (locationOutdoor && intensityIntense &&
      (+aloneSelected == compositionAloneData ||
        +friendsSelected == compositionFriendsData ||
        +partnersSelected == compositionPartnersData ||
        +familyWithKidsSelected == compositionFamilyWithKidsData ||
        +groupSelected == compositionGroupsData ||
        +colleaugesSelected == compositionColleagues)) {
      console.log('location en intensity en composition');
      return (
        locationInput == outdoorData &&
        intensityInput == intensityData &&
        +aloneSelected == compositionAloneData //&& 
        +friendsSelected == compositionFriendsData &&
        +partnersSelected == compositionPartnersData &&
        +familyWithKidsSelected == compositionFamilyWithKidsData &&
        +groupSelected == compositionGroupsData &&
        +colleaugesSelected == compositionColleagues
      );

    } else if (!locationOutdoor && intensityIntense) {
      console.log('alleen intensity');
      return intensityInput == intensityData;
    } else if (!locationOutdoor && !intensityIntense) {
      console.log('niks');
      return this.state.oldData;
    } else {
      console.log('blabl')
    }
  }); this.setState({
    dataSource: newData
  }); this.props.navigation.setParams({
    searchVal: false
  });
};
```

I'm sorry if it is not fully explained or something is unclear, I am working on this for 2 days now and I get a bit tired due to it.

Comment: It is really hard to read all this code. Could you, please, consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: some sample data and html code to prototype with would be helpful

Comment: Why do you do it in front-end? I think you'd better do it on the back-end. Explore Headless CMS term.

Comment: The fact that `+aloneSelected == compositionAloneData //&&` is commented out changes that section of your `if` statement effectively to `(+aloneSelected == (compositionAloneData + friendsSelected)) == compositionFriendsData` which I doubt is what you want.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts yes that's a mistake I corrected it when I saw it but haven't pasted it here yet, however it doesn't fix the issue.